# on_mouse_down called for every button (even scroll wheel movements)

Tags: python, pgzero

I am using `pgzero` for implementing a game and have found out that the `on_mouse_down` hook function is even called when I move/roll the scroll wheel. This is surprising.

How can I prevent this?

```
import pgzrun
import pgzero

def on_mouse_down(pos):
    print("mouse down hook called")

pgzrun.go()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`on_mouse_down` takes more parameters than you're currently getting. The second one is the button:

```
def on_mouse_down(pos, button):
    if button == mouse.LEFT:
        print("mouse down hook called")
```

Comment: Damn easy, I should have known this, it is documented in the API: https://pygame-zero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/hooks.html#on_mouse_down